# Plan from Revit becomes a picture in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit

So when I export my Revit file to the Forge Viewer the 2D plan I want to look at does not have any selectable elements because it somehow was exported as a picture.
It is only my assumption that it was exported as a picture since it becomes blurry when I zoom in. Is this a known issue or does my plan need a special property to be able to be translated to forge properly?
Using a demo file everything works perfectly but using a file coming from a different source does not seem to work properly

Comment: have you selected those views using "Publish Settings" on Revit?

Comment: yes, with and without publish settings, only thing selectable in forge is the title of the plan which somehow is not there in the revit file. I selected the same view in revit as well as in forge. The lines which indicate sections are somehow not blurry but also not selectable.

Comment: not sure what's the problem here, if you have a non-confidential file that you can share, please email to forge.help[at]autodesk.com

Comment: it seems that if you view contains non-vector pieces, like images, the Revit engines render it as a single image, which can cause this behavior.

Comment: I see, thank you for the information. Sadly the file is confidential so I am not able to share it. The workaround is to convert it to IFC and open it with Revit again, then publish the views I want to see and then load it in Forge. Sadly some parts lost their geometry but it works overall

Comment: Hey, so trying to resolve it I saw the plan contains viewport of a structural plan. in revit I can activate the view but is this also possible in forge?

Comment: You need to select the views to export on Revit, then Forge will follow that.

Comment: yes I did that and it still handles it like a picture even though I removed all the images from the project. How can I determine non vector pieces?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons for a view to becoming a raster:

- uses shading, shadows, gradients, or sketchy lines.
- is rendered.
- contains an image.
- uses point clouds.
- contains a decal. (Includes Revit Annotation elements, such as section, spot, text, and etc.)

Comment: I see, I tried removing the plan from the whole revit file and putting it into an own revit file only containing this single element and it somehow became useable even though it contains decals. Thank you for your help! I will try to avoid these in the future